# Ubuntu one stuck in rescan

Tags: ubuntu-one

trying to sync about 80 gigs of data. It has been several days. 
This is my syncd log
[Log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/583164/)

exceptions log
[Ex Log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/583165/)

Answer (score 1):

Your case seem this FAQ https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyIsItTakingSoLongForMyFilesToSync

Comment: Yep, this is right. It's related to slow processing of many files. If you use Ubuntu 11.04 then things will improve. We're also finishing changes on the server that combined with the client in 11.04 gives significant performance improvements. Those changes should be completed within the next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's I fixed this issue on my 10.04:

1. Stop sync-daemon using `u1sdtool -q`
2. Rename `~/.local/share/ubuntuone` to something else (like `ubuntuone_old` or something)
3. Start sync-daemon using `u1sdtool -s`

This will force creation of a fresh new UbuntuOne directory.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.4 is going to end support. Please try to provide a updated solution.